# Is the sentence "Comment ce garçon a résolu un cube rubix en seulement six secondes ?" correct?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

Is the following sentence correct?

> Comment ce garçon de quinze ans a résolu un cube rubix en seulement six secondes ?

I want it to be translated into

> How did this fifteen year old boy solve a rubix cube in just six seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not grammatically correct. If it is a question as you wonder how he did you should say:

> Comment ce garçon de quinze ans a-t-il résolu un Rubik's Cube en seulement six secondes ?

If it is a declaration, like the title of something that will explain how the kid did it:

> Comment le garçon de quinze ans résolut un Rubik's Cube en seulement six secondes.

However you will often see it as you have written on the Internet, mostly because journalists do not care about correct grammar. So if you want a parody of these titles your phrase is what you need.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I sound a bit stupid but why is it necessary to add the "il"? Is it a reflexive verb? Can you explain everything, thanks!

Comment: In French to express an interrogation you have to invert the verb and the subject, as you do in English for yes/no questions, for example: "Are you a doctor?" -> "**Êtes-vous** docteur ?" or "How many kids do you have ?" -> "Combien d'enfants **avez-vous** ?" You put some "-" between them and when it is difficult to pronounce you add a "t" as in "a-t-il ?", the interrogative form of "il a".

Comment: I would just add that "Comment cet enfant a résolu [...] ?" is a very common way to phrase things in oral / colloquial French. As Anne said it's not grammatically correct, and you shouldn't *write* it, but we *say* it much more often than the correct form with verb - subject inversion.

Comment: You might say "Comment a ce garçon [...] résolu [...]" but it would separate to much "a" and "résolu" which are the two parts of the same verb. Using the pronoun "il" to refer to "ce garçon de quinze ans" makes it clearer

Comment: You could also say "Comment est-ce que ce garçon de quinze ans a résolu un rubix cube en seulement six secondes ?"

Comment: Très juste, comet, je corrige ça en "Rubik's Cube". Comme c'est une marque ça n'a pas vraiment de sens de le traduire mais "rubix" ne vient de nulle part.